# What are the advantages of Flask-Script?

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a fairly simple [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) app that requires a cron job. Right now, I have a separate module that imports the classes it needs from my app module. This seems to work just fine.

I stumbled across [Flask-Script](http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and I'm left wondering why it would be used over the solution I have now. Keeping in mind that I am new to Flask, can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a helper module. It just gives you a nice "router" for command line commands instead of URLs.

It's more convenient and (more importantly) easier to read the intent of the code.
 - Especially for non-trivial cases (>200loc)